# Can you color specific sections in an HTML5 range slider?

Tags: css, html, slider, range

Within a stepped HTML5 range slider, I need to make the background color different for different steps (like the image below). Is this possible?

[image: Slider with colored sections]

Answer (score 0):

you can use -ms-fill-lower -ms-fill-upper css property to add upper and lower color changes. But this will work only in IE.

You can use some scripting to get more desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with gradients using CSS3. CSS3 gradients let you display smooth transitions between two or more specified colors also for range slider for html5.

It works on all browsers, But Internet Explorer must be 10+ Version.